# LUIS Container '/luis/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}' v2.0 endpoint returns 'Unsupported slot name' Error

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm running the luis container `'mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/luis:latest'` locally and since the latest update that added the v3 Endpoints, when I attempt to get a prediction using the `'/luis/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}'` endpoint I get back an `500`.

**Example:**

```
GET http://localhost:5000/luis/v2.0/apps/{appId}/versions/0.65?q=Hello&timezoneOffset=0&verbose=false&log=true&spellCheck=false
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Could not process LUIS request: 'Unsupported slot name v0.65'"
    }
}
```

This was working great before the last update, so it seems like something with the new image broke the v2.0 api.  Anyone else run into this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please check is slot name v0.65 existing, if not please change to the correct slot name. Please refer the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-how-to-manage-versions) for manage versions.